# Dispay non-String variable to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I wonder if JLabel really can't display a value beside String and Icon. For example for displaying Clock variable..

```
Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
```

And the JLabel `setText()` method as following..

```
label.setText(clock);
```

I'm aware that `setText()` method only works with String parameter. But since clock variable can't be converted to String, i really have no idea how to display it on the label. Or what should i use instead of JLabel to display Clock variables.

I tried `label.setText(Clock.valueOf(clock));`, until later i realized that only works for primitive data (or no?). I really stuck at this moment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels o boy...i just realized i can use LocalTime instead. I'm beginner here :D this is embarrassing.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a Clock. I would suspect you should be using the Calendar class or Date class. Each of these classes has a String representation of the current time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay gonna try that one

Comment: @camickr Yeah my fault, just realize that either.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using `java.time.Clock`. You can convert the current time into an ISO-8601 string by doing `clock.instant().toString()`.

Therefore, you can put the clock in the label using:

```
label.setText(clock.instant().toString());
```

If you want the label to show the clock updating, you may need to use something like a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to reset the label text every second.

You can change the formatting if you don't want ISO-8601 with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to set your own format.

Comment: (1+), guess its time I learned the new Java 8 Date/Time API's.

Comment: It doesn't works. `method setText in class JLabel cannot be applied to given types`

Comment: @camickr me two :/, +1

Answer (score 0):

JLabel will set the text to an object
if you have overridden the toString() method
and call to it..

As

```
System.out.println(clock); //this would automatically call the toString() method.
```

For this.. You would have to directly call it.

```
label.setText(clock.toString());
```